# Which is the better option for tabs?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-tabhost

I have read different examples for tabs with activities and views. I know there are certain limitations for each. Currently i want to know which one would be a better option for my problem. I have 4 tabs and each of them have the same list view but the content of each list would be different.

I have tried the following approach:
Creating the tab activity and having single activity for list and loading the same list for each tab with different content altogether. Somehow this does not seem to be correct way.

Help me find a good approach. Thanks Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use different activity for different tab.Like this:

```
intent = new Intent().setClass(Tabhost.this, ArtistsActivity.class);

// Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator("Artists",
                  res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
              .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

And have a look [android developer site](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html).

Comment: I have used the single activity with different views now. I could not see any downside of this.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to implement a different activity for each list.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply update the content of the list and don't update the view when you click the tabs.